# SwiftUI Picker doesn't update data when selecting a new row

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

SwiftUI Picker doesn't update data when selecting a new row.
I tried to pass the data via Binding, but it didn't seem to work.
When I remove the Binding logic, it all works fine as I expected.

ContentView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Tartan"]

    @State private var showPicker: Bool = false
    @Binding var selectedColor: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        PanelView(showPicker: .constant(false))
        
            VStack {
                Picker("Please choose a color", selection: $selectedColor) {
                    ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
}
```

PanelView.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct PanelView: View {

    @Binding var showPicker: Bool
    @State private var selectedColor = "Red"
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("You selected: \(selectedColor)")
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my English, hope someone can take a look at this problem.

Comment: Your `selectedColor` is bound to nothing, as well as your `showPicker`... read carefully your code. And take some basic SwiftUI tutorials about State/Binding cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.constant` is a dead end don't use it anywhere but in the `Previews` section to simulate a source of truth.

`@State` is a source of truth, it has no parent.

`@Binding` is a two-way connection. It does not have the ability to hold a value.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue", "Tartan"]

    @State private var showPicker: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedColor: String = "Red"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        PanelView(showPicker: $showPicker, selectedColor: $selectedColor)
        
            VStack {
                Picker("Please choose a color", selection: $selectedColor) {
                    ForEach(colors, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
            }
        
    }
}

struct PanelView: View {

    @Binding var showPicker: Bool
    @Binding var selectedColor : String
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Text("You selected: \(selectedColor)")
        }
    }
}
```

Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) all of this is pretty basic stuff.